# how to use model function from view ? - laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, function, model, eloquent

i made a function into model class which is

```
public function scopetest($query)
    {
 return $query->pluck('name');
    }
  }
```

and my controller code is

```
 public function index()
     {
     $books = Book::all();

     return view('welcome',compact('books'));

       }
```

to get the test() function result I wrote my view file

```
@foreach($books as $book)

 {{$book->test()}}

@endforeach
```

but problem is when i visit this page it will show 'name' field value 3 times. why it show 3 times? how to call model function from view? & what is the right process? kindly help please[image: view result]

Comment: It is showing 3 times may be because you are looping?

Comment: looping? but where?

Comment: do you want to call scopetest function from blade view?

Comment: You are getting all books record and in your views you loop using the foreach. For each iteration, you call the test function. That is why it shows three times. I guess, you have three books record in your db

Comment: @sunil yes i want to call scopetest()  from view

Comment: @geckob i have one record in books table & it shows 3times. This is problem. And i want to know what is the right process to call a model function from view?

Comment: @Masum just use namespace of your model like \App\ModelName->scopetest($your_value);

Comment: @Masum please check my answer this will solve your problem.

Comment: tnx all for trying to help me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are many ways to call a model function in the view.

Method 1:

Pass Some Modal to view in your controller like :

```
$model = Model::find(1);
View::make('view')->withModel($model);
```

In modal create a some function:

```
  public function someFunction() {
   // do something
  }
```

In view you can call this function directly as:

```
{{$model->someFunction()}}
```

Method 2 or other way:

You can make a static function in the model like:

```
public static function someStaticFunction($par1, $par2) {
   // do what you need
}
```

And in your view you can model function directly as:

```
{{App\Model::someStaticFunction($par1,$par2)}}
```

Comment: @Masum welcome and if solution is working for you so you may vote up to help others.

Comment: I want to vote you. but I don't know where is voting option?

Answer (score 0):

The scope should be `scopeTest()` (camelCase).

Comment: my target is building some query into model function & get it from blade file. so what is the right process? how to you do it?