# function in model in laravel to display age

Tags: php, laravel

i create function in laravel to calculate age and display it in view but i get this error

```
Call to undefined method stdClass::age()
```

This is my model

```
use Carbon\Carbon;


  public function age() 
    {
    return $this->date_de_naissance->diffInYears(Carbon::now());
    }
```

This is my view:

```
 @foreach  ($patient as $pat ) 

              <tr>
                <td><a href="#" >{{ $pat->nom }}</a> </td>
                 <td> {{ $pat->prenom }} </td>
                  <td> {{ $pat->nom_epouse }} </td>
                  <td> {{ $pat->age() }}  </td>//
                  <td>{{ $pat->sexe }}</td>
                 </tr>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42357941/how-to-use-model-function-from-view-laravel-5-4

Comment: `$pat` doesn't seem to be an instance of the model

Comment: where is this method `public function age()` in? is it on the model? what error did you get? are you sure passing the model? have you tried Jaydp suggestion?

Comment: @BagusTesa the function in the model and i get a error Call to undefined method stdClass::age()

Comment: and yes i tried Jaydp suggestion but no luck

Comment: What's the class of the model and how are you getting `$patient`?

Answer (score 1):

you can always define this code in your Model

```
protected $dates=['date_de_naissance'];
```

and then you can directly use this in your loop.

```
{{$pat->date_de_naissance->diffInYears(\Carbon::now())}}
```

instead of

```
{{ $pat->age() }}
```

**Note: By defining a column name in protected array $dates, your value automatically becomes an instance of carbon while calling**

Answer (score 0):

In case you didn't know, you can convert `Date` or `Datetime` or whatever date format to `age` using Carbon [`->age`](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-getters):

```
Carbon::parse($pat->date_de_naissance)->age;
```

You need to modify `$patient` in `controller` before sending it to `view` because it's easier to call Carbon in `controller`.

```
foreach($patient as $pat)
    $pat['date_de_naissance'] = Carbon::parse($pat['date_de_naissance'])->age;
```

Answer (score 0):

For now this below solved my problem

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Patient as pat;


class Patient extends Model
{
       use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */

    protected $fillable = [
        'nom', 'id_pat', 'nom_epouse','prenom','sexe','date_de_naissance','etat_civil','id_chicha','id_tab','id_alc','id_neffa','id_autres',
    ];
    protected $table="patients";


    public static function getAge($pat) 
    {


 return Carbon::parse($pat->date_de_naissance)->diffInYears(Carbon::now());
     }

}
```

Comment: you can always define `protected $dates=['date_de_naissance'];` and then you can directly use `$pat->date_de_naissance->diffInYears(Carbon::now())` in your loop.